# How to find full path of Internet Explorer(IE)'s cache file?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, caching

OS : Windows 7 64bit
IE Version : 9

When I open

```
C:\Users\<USERNAME>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files
```

directory with explorer.exe, IE cache files are there.

But files aren't there.

For Example, if **commonPerson.js** is in cache file,

its real path is **C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Low\Content.IE5\3IM78NQJ\commonPerson.js**

I guess other path is fixed and 3IM78NQJ is determined by some rules(Hash?).

[Nirsoft's IECacheView](http://www.naver.com) contains what I want to make and I'll do it with C++.

How can I find real path of each cache file?

Is there any well-known rule or index file which contains information about file's path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GetUrlCacheEntryInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384185%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is the proper API to use to map an URL to it's cache file location.

Depending on your situation you may also need to use the [FindFirst/FindNextUrlCacheEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384026%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions.

Answer (score -1):

Vista and later:

```
SHGetKnownFolderPath(FOLDERID_InternetCache, .....)
```

earlier:

```
SHGetFolderPath(....., CSIDL_INTERNET_CACHE, .....)
```

You still have to iterate subdirectories yourself.